# Logic for static triangular plot

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been trying to make a static d3 v5 version based off [this block](http://bl.ocks.org/tomgp/7674234) for the past few days. I have the coordinate plane drawn, but I am having trouble adapting the plot logic to a static variant. Here is my progress:

```js
var margins = {top:50, bottom:50, left:50, right:50};

var height = 900;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var side = 700;
var axis_labels = ['Journalist','Developer','Designer'];
var axis_ticks = [0,20,40,60,80,100];
var tickLabelMargin = 10;
var axisLabelMargin = 40;
var minor_axis_ticks = d3.range(0, 101, 5);
console.log(minor_axis_ticks)
var w = side;
var h = Math.sqrt( side*side - (side/2)*(side/2));

var corners = [
  [margins.left, h + margins.top], // a
  [ w + margins.left, h + margins.top], //b
  [(w/2) + margins.left, margins.top] ]; //c

var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', totalWidth)
    .attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

var axes = graphGroup.append('g').attr('class','axes');

var plot = {
  dataset:[]
};

var data = [
  {journalist:75,developer:25,designer:0,label:'point 1'},
  {journalist:70,developer:10,designer:20,label:'point 2'},
  {journalist:75,developer:20,designer:5,label:'point 3'},


  {journalist:5,developer:60,designer:35,label:'point 4'},
  {journalist:10,developer:80,designer:10,label:'point 5'},
  {journalist:10,developer:90,designer:0,label:'point 6'},
  {journalist:20,developer:70,designer:10,label:'point 7'},

  {journalist:10,developer:20,designer:70,label:'point 8'},
  {journalist:15,developer:5,designer:80,label:'point 9'},
  {journalist:10,developer:10,designer:80,label:'point 10'},
  {journalist:20,developer:10,designer:70,label:'point 11'},
 ];

  function lineAttributes(p1, p2){
      return { x1:p1[0], y1:p1[1],
           x2:p2[0], y2:p2[1] };
  }

axes.selectAll('.axis-title')
  .data(axis_labels)
  .enter()
   .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis-title')
    .attr('transform',function(d,i){
     return 'translate('+corners[i][0]+','+corners[i][1]+')';
    })
    .append('text')
    .text(function(d){ return d; })
    .attr('text-anchor', function(d,i){
     if(i===0) return 'end';
     if(i===2) return 'middle';
     return 'start';

    })
    .attr('transform', function(d,i){
     var theta = 0;
     if(i===0) theta = 120;
     if(i===1) theta = 60;
     if(i===2) theta = -90;

     var x = axisLabelMargin * Math.cos(theta * 0.0174532925),
      y = axisLabelMargin * Math.sin(theta * 0.0174532925);
     return 'translate('+x+','+y+')'
    });


        var n = axis_ticks.length;
         if(minor_axis_ticks){
          minor_axis_ticks.forEach(function(v) {
           var coord1 = coord( [v, 0, 100-v] );
           var coord2 = coord( [v, 100-v, 0] );
           var coord3 = coord( [0, 100-v, v] );
           var coord4 = coord( [100-v, 0, v] );

           axes.append("line")
            .attr('x1', lineAttributes(coord1, coord2).x1 )
                .attr('x2', lineAttributes(coord1, coord2).x2 )
                .attr('y1', lineAttributes(coord1, coord2).y1 )
                .attr('y2', lineAttributes(coord1, coord2).y2 )
            .classed('a-axis minor-tick', true);

           axes.append("line")
                .attr('x1', lineAttributes(coord2, coord3).x1 )
                .attr('x2', lineAttributes(coord2, coord3).x2 )
                .attr('y1', lineAttributes(coord2, coord3).y1 )
                .attr('y2', lineAttributes(coord2, coord3).y2 )
            .classed('b-axis minor-tick', true);

           axes.append("line")
                .attr('x1', lineAttributes(coord3, coord4).x1 )
                .attr('x2', lineAttributes(coord3, coord4).x2 )
                .attr('y1', lineAttributes(coord3, coord4).y1 )
                .attr('y2', lineAttributes(coord3, coord4).y2 )
            .classed('c-axis minor-tick', true);
          });
         }

          axis_ticks.forEach(function(v) {
          var coord1 = coord( [v, 0, 100-v] );
          var coord2 = coord( [v, 100-v, 0] );
          var coord3 = coord( [0, 100-v, v] );
          var coord4 = coord( [100-v, 0, v] );

          axes.append("line")
              .attr('x1', lineAttributes(coord1, coord2).x1 )
              .attr('x2', lineAttributes(coord1, coord2).x2 )
              .attr('y1', lineAttributes(coord1, coord2).y1 )
              .attr('y2', lineAttributes(coord1, coord2).y2 )
           .classed('a-axis tick', true);

          axes.append("line")
              .attr('x1', lineAttributes(coord2, coord3).x1 )
              .attr('x2', lineAttributes(coord2, coord3).x2 )
              .attr('y1', lineAttributes(coord2, coord3).y1 )
              .attr('y2', lineAttributes(coord2, coord3).y2 )
           .classed('b-axis tick', true);

          axes.append("line")
              .attr('x1', lineAttributes(coord3, coord4).x1 )
              .attr('x2', lineAttributes(coord3, coord4).x2 )
              .attr('y1', lineAttributes(coord3, coord4).y1 )
              .attr('y2', lineAttributes(coord3, coord4).y2 )
           .classed('c-axis tick', true);

              //tick labels
            axes.append('g')
             .attr('transform',function(d){
              return 'translate(' + coord1[0] + ',' + coord1[1] + ')'
             })
             .append("text")
              .attr('transform','rotate(60)')
              .attr('text-anchor','end')
              .attr('x',-tickLabelMargin)
              .text( function (d) { return v; } )
              .classed('a-axis tick-text', true );

            axes.append('g')
             .attr('transform',function(d){
              return 'translate(' + coord2[0] + ',' + coord2[1] + ')'
             })
             .append("text")
              .attr('transform','rotate(-60)')
              .attr('text-anchor','end')
              .attr('x',-tickLabelMargin)
              .text( function (d) { return (100- v); } )
              .classed('b-axis tick-text', true);

            axes.append('g')
             .attr('transform',function(d){
              return 'translate(' + coord3[0] + ',' + coord3[1] + ')'
             })
             .append("text")
              .text( function (d) { return v; } )
              .attr('x',tickLabelMargin)
              .classed('c-axis tick-text', true);

           })



          function coord(arr){
            var a = arr[0], b=arr[1], c=arr[2];
            var sum, pos = [0,0];
              sum = a + b + c;
              if(sum !== 0) {
                a /= sum;
                b /= sum;
                c /= sum;
              pos[0] =  corners[0][0]  * a + corners[1][0]  * b + corners[2][0]  * c;
              pos[1] =  corners[0][1]  * a + corners[1][1]  * b + corners[2][1]  * c;
            }
              return pos;
          }

          function scale(p, factor) {
             return [p[0] * factor, p[1] * factor];
         }

          plot.data = function(data, accessor, bindBy){ //bind by is the dataset property used as an id for the join
          plot.dataset = data;
            console.log(data)

          var circles = graphGroup.selectAll("circle")
           .data( data.map( function(d){ return coord(accessor(d)); }), function(d,i){
            if(bindBy){
             return plot.dataset[i][bindBy];
            }
            return i;
           } );

          circles.enter().append("circle");

          circles.transition().attr("cx", function (d) { return d[0]; })
           .attr("cy", function (d) { return d[1]; })
           .attr("r", 6);

          return this;
         }

          plot.getPosition = coord;
         plot.getTripple = function(x, y){
          //TODO, get percentages for a give x, y
         }
plot.data(data);
```

```css
line.tick {
   stroke-width: 0.5;
  }

  line.minor-tick {
   stroke-width: 1;
   stroke-opacity:0.1;
  }

  .a-axis{
   stroke: #333;
  }

  .b-axis{
   stroke: #333;
  }

  .c-axis{
   stroke: #333;
  }

  .axis-title{
   font-family: TW Cen MT;
   font-size: 1.5rem;
  }

  text.tick-text {
   font-family: TW Cen MT;
   font-weight: lighter;
   font-size: 1rem;
   fill: #333;
   stroke:none;
  }

  circle {
   fill: #fff1e0;
   stroke: #DB7365;
   stroke-width: 2px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

For the moment I'm trying to stay close to the original code and am using `plot.data(data);` to draw the graph. Again, my goal is to make a static version of the chart, and I'd rather not have to call any functions to "draw" the plot. I just want the chart to be drawn without having to fuss with passing different parameters to different functions. I am not making progress anymore, and have become lost in all the criss-crossing of functions.

It is at this point that I am hit with the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: accessor is not a function

citing line 257:

`.data( data.map( function(d){ return coord(accessor(d)); }), function(d,i){`

### Question

Given I wish to make a static visual, what is the appropriate choice for "accessor" when I call `plot.data()`? Once I figure out what exactly "accessor" is supposed to be, I will seek to recode to remove the necessity to pass values to the function.

Context for accessor pertains to this function (line 252):

`plot.data = function(data, accessor, bindBy){`

Comment: *"I'd rather not have to call any functions to "draw" the plot"*... why? Even in simple projects that create a simple dataviz, is always a good idea having specific functions for specific tasks. That doesn't mean the code is reusable.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I take your point. I am usually not opposed to a few functions for such tasks, but in this case there are too many functions, and it's preventing me from building an intuition as to what is happening. The whole `accessor` parameter is still a black box at this point. Just looking to simplify when possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your **real** question is quite a big one: a huge refactor in that bl.ocks.

Therefore, I'll address only your **strict** question here. The `accessor` in this argument list...

```
plot.data = function(data, accessor, bindBy)
```

...is this function:

```
function(d){ 
    return [d.journalist, d.developer, d.designer]
};
```

That is, it just creates an array with the three variables in each object of the data array.

That array, as you probably know, will be used by `coord()`:

```
function coord(arr) {
    var a = arr[0],
        b = arr[1],
        c = arr[2];
    var sum, pos = [0, 0];
    sum = a + b + c;
    if (sum !== 0) {
        a /= sum;
        b /= sum;
        c /= sum;
        pos[0] = corners[0][0] * a + corners[1][0] * b + corners[2][0] * c;
        pos[1] = corners[0][1] * a + corners[1][1] * b + corners[2][1] * c;
    }
    return pos;
}
```